# CSS template 3 columns overlap wrapper / header / footer

Tags: css, templates

i dont have any idea for create this layout using CSS :

header is 100% with and fixed in top ( `margin:0 padding:0` ).
wrapper is overlap of header (`e.g : 20px;` )
`Left` sidebar and `content` and `right` side is auto height for dynamic content ! So `footer` is moving to down if `Left/content/Right` moved. 
The `wrapper` is Overlap of `footer`. 
please see picture :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuhBU.png

How To create this for all browser !? Thanks For Any Help.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can take a look?

Comment: I dont have any idea for write this code. Sorry!!!

Comment: This is a fairly large task. I suggest you take a look at grid 960 (http://960.gs/) and see if that gets you started.  I am happy to help with any issues but not do it all for you.

Comment: @Zoidberg Thanks .Having friends like you I feel happy

Answer (score 1):

Its better to read the article so you can get some knowledge about html layouts. Please see below link it might help you to understand how to design and create custom layout as per requirement.

http://zomigi.com/blog/essential-resources-for-creating-liquid-and-elastic-layouts/

Comment: Big & nice Documents. Thanks.